# Issues with trying contact form that outputs to my email

Tags: php, html

So I'm in a web design class in school right now and I want to set up a contact page that will send the results to my email. I followed a really good tutorial and made sure I typed everything correct but it wont send. I'm using freehosting.com to host my pages.

Here's my index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Email Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <p class="header">E-MAIL FORM</p>
            <form class="contact-form" action="contactform.php" method="post">
                <p class="title">Your Name</p>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholer="Full Name"><br/>
                <p class="title">Your E-Mail</p>
                <input type="text" name="mail" placeholer="Your E-mail"><br/>
                <p class="title">Subject</p>
                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholer="Subject"><br/>
                <p class="title">Message</p>
                <textarea name="message" maxrows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br/>
                <button type="submit" name="submit"><h2>SUBMIT</h2></button><br/>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
```

Here's my contactform.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = "terryjtowell@terrytowell.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an Email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: index.php?mailsend");
}
```

Any help would be great. I'm new to PHP but really familiar with html. the live link for the test contact form is terrytowell.com/test/index.php  I've made sure to upload my code to a live hosting service so that I'll be able to use server-side scripting. Thanks

Comment: Try sending the mail from a real account on your server, Lots of hosts wont send mail unless the from is a valid checkable address on your server to stop Spam

Comment: And use the users email as a replyTo address instead

Comment: The mail() function returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise. Check that so we can dismiss problems on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right. The problem comes from your hosting.

Freehosting.com won't allow you to use mail() function unless you pay for an addon. It's all explained here -> https://www.freehosting.com/client/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=25